# Crystal Report - Report Header Section

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have created a Report using Crystal Report(Visual Studio 2005 and .NET Framework 2.0). In the Report Header section I have added a TextBox control to display header for the report. But when I execute the application the Text in the Report Header section is not displayed.

What should I do to view the text entered in the report header section?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the report header invisible in all the pages?

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure you're running the most up to date copy of the report in the application?

The default behavior for the report header and textbox is that they are visible unless specified otherwise.

2) If the report header is being suppressed, it will appear as a darker shade than normally visible sections.  If the report header looks to be suppressed, you need to check the Section Expert for the **Suppress** checkbox associated with the report header section (it can be set conditionally - kill the button next to the Suppress checkbox to see if there's any code.  Generally the button text is red if there is any conditional logic).

3) If the report header is visible with no interference, check the suppression logic for the texbox - right click on the textbox, click properties.  Same checklist as for the report header.